# In a library that uses metaclasses a lot, how can I avoid annoying the user with metaclass conflicts?

Tags: python, metaclass

The library I'm writing makes heavy use of metaclasses. As an example, here is a basic singleton implementation:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instance = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._instance is None:
            self._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

        return self._instance

class ExampleSingleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    pass
```

This works perfectly fine, but problems arise when multiple inheritance is used and the other class also has a metaclass. Metaclasses are fairly common in the standard library; the most notable is [`abc.ABCMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta). A naive attempt to make an abstract singleton fails:

```
class AbstractSingleton(ExampleSingleton, abc.ABC):
    pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 25, in <module>
    class AbstractSingleton(ExampleSingleton, abc.ABC):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

The workaround is easy enough - create a new metaclass that inherits from `SingletonMeta` and `ABCMeta` - but it's really annoying for anyone who wants to use my library.

```
class AbstractSingletonMeta(SingletonMeta, abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class AbstractSingleton(metaclass=AbstractSingletonMeta):
    pass

# no metaclass conflict
```

What's the best way to deal with this problem?

Some of my ideas:

1. Since abstract classes are fairly common, I could make `SingletonMeta` a subclass of `ABCMeta`.
2. I could implement `AbstractSingletonMeta` in my library for the user's convenience.
3. Since any callable can be used as a metaclass, I could implement a function that automatically merges the metaclasses of all parent classes. (The usage would be like `class AbstractSingleton(ExampleSingleton, abc.ABC, metaclass=auto_merge_metaclasses):`)
4. In the spirit of "explicit is better than implicit", I could do nothing and let the user sort out the metaclass conflicts.

Comment: Are you aware of this?
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/

Comment: @cha0site Yes, that's where I got the idea to make a function that resolves the metaclass conflicts from. I'm not convinced it's the best solution though, hence my question. (You *can* post that as answer if you want though. It's definitely a useful approach, and the votes will decide which approach is the best.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the information about the needed metaclasses and what needs to be combined is already present in the base classes, and those are passed to the metaclass call, it is possible to have a callable that will inspect all the bases and their used metaclasses, and dynamically create a combining metaclass.

The `types` module have some callables that otherwise make it easy to pick the correct metaclass for a set of base classes. So, the function bellow should suffice to your needs, if all your used metaclasses are combinable in an arbitrary order:

```
from types import prepare_class

def combine_meta(name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
    metaclasses = {prepare_class(name, (base,))[0] for base in bases}
    metaclasses.discard(type)

    if len(metaclasses) > 1:
        meta_name = '_'.join(mcs.__name__ for mcs in metaclasses)
        metaclass = combine_meta(meta_name, tuple(metaclasses), {})
    elif len(metaclasses) == 1:
        metaclass = metaclasses.pop()
    else:
        metaclass = type
    return metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
```

I've tested this with this sequence in the interactive interpreter, and it worked that far:

```
class M1(type): pass
class M2(type): pass
class A(metaclass=M1): pass
class B(metaclass=M2): pass
class C(A, B): pass  # This raises a metaclassconflict
class C(A, B, metaclass=combine_meta): pass
```

Comment: I think class `C` needs to be defined like `class C(A, B, metaclass=combine_meta): pass`, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. the history was missing the last, and most importante line.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. I took the liberty to make your function recursive so that it doesn't crash if the metaclasses have conflicting metaclasses.

Comment: Great exploit of a non-type metaclass. You might be interested in reviewing my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78139041/6890912), where I evolved your solution to address two limitations.

Answer (score 1):

@jsbueno's solution is great, though it has two major limitations.

Firstly, if one of the two metaclasses involved inherits from the other:

```
class M1(type):
    pass

class M2(M1):
    pass

class A(metaclass=M1):
    pass

class B(metaclass=M2):
    pass

class C(A, B, metaclass=combine_meta):
    pass
```

it would produce the following exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases M1, M2
```

This issue could be solved by retaining only the most derived of the metaclasses involved.

And secondly, if one or more of the metaclasses involved, such as `enum.EnumMeta`, has a custom namespace prepared:

```
from abc import ABC
from enum import Enum

class Foo(ABC, Enum, metaclass=combine_meta):
    pass
```

then with @jsbueno's solution, the code above would produce:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_member_names'
```

And this issue could be solved by making `combine_meta` a callable singleton capable of preparing a merged namespace itself. This is done with a `__prepare__` method that calls the `__prepare__` method of each metaclass and merges the returning namespaces. If a non-dict namespace is encountered, let the more specialized namespace take over. Since two non-dict namespaces can't be expected to reliably work together, the merging process should raise an exception if (and only if) it encounters more than one non-dict type of namespaces.

Also worth noting is that @jsbueno's solution doesn't retain the order of the metaclasses with its use of a set, and this can be remedied by storing metaclasses in a list instead.

Below is a solution with the issues above addressed:

```
class CombineMeta:
    def __prepare__(self, name, bases, **kwargs):
        namespace = {}
        for metaclass in self._get_most_derived_metaclasses(bases):
            ns = metaclass.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs)
            if type(ns) in (dict, type(namespace)):
                namespace.update(ns)
            else:
                if type(namespace) is not dict:
                    raise TypeError('metaclass conflict: '
                                    'multiple custom namespaces defined.')
                ns.update(namespace)
                namespace = ns
        return namespace

    def __call__(self, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        metaclasses = self._get_most_derived_metaclasses(bases)
        if len(metaclasses) > 1:
            merged_name = '__'.join(meta.__name__ for meta in metaclasses)
            ns = self.__prepare__(merged_name, metaclasses)
            metaclass = self(merged_name, tuple(metaclasses), ns, **kwargs)
        else:
            metaclass, = metaclasses or (type,)
        return metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_most_derived_metaclasses(bases):
        metaclasses = []
        for metaclass in map(type, bases):
            if metaclass is not type:
                metaclasses = [other for other in metaclasses
                        if not issubclass(metaclass, other)]
                if not any(issubclass(other, metaclass)
                        for other in metaclasses):
                    metaclasses.append(metaclass)
        return metaclasses

combine_meta = CombineMeta()
```

so that both test cases would work without errors:

```
class C(A, B, metaclass=combine_meta):
    pass

class Foo(ABC, Enum, metaclass=combine_meta):
    pass
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/9T51QI